# Tensorflow: Reshape a tensor according to a boolean mask

Tags: tensorflow

I have a 1D tensor of values:
a = tf.constant([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4])

and a nD boolean mask:
b = tf.constant([[1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1]])

The total number of 1's in b matches the length of a.

How can I get [[0.1, 0.2, 0.0], [0.0, 0.3, 0.4]] from a and b?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.constant([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4])

b = tf.constant([[1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1]])

# reshape b to a 1D vector
b_res = tf.reshape(b, [-1])
# Get the indices to gather using cumsum
b_cum = tf.cumsum(b_res) - 1

# Gather the elements, multiply by b_res to zero out the unwanted values and reshape back
c = tf.reshape(tf.gather(a, b_cum) * tf.cast(b_res, 'float32'), [-1, 3])
print(c)
```